# Moving rows google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to transfer rows of data from Sheet 1 to Sheet 2.

Thank you

Comment: See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for "Best practices" -> Get the values array  and setValues array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- Your script works fine. But, you want to reduce the process cost of your script.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

In this modification, the rows are copied using `setValues` and deleted by Sheets API. By this, I thought that the process cost might be able to be reduced a little. So, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services before you use this script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```js
function archive() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var firstSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet 1");
  var firstSheetValues = firstSheet.getRange(1, 1, firstSheet.getLastRow(), firstSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var sheetId = firstSheet.getSheetId();
  var {values, requests} = firstSheetValues.reduce(function (o, r, i) {
    if (r[1] == "Archive") {
      o.values.push(r);
      o.requests.push({ deleteDimension: { range: { sheetId, startIndex: i, endIndex: i + 1, dimension: "ROWS" } } });
    }
    return o;
  }, { values: [], requests: [] });
  var secondSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet 2");
  secondSheet.getRange(secondSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({requests: requests.reverse()}, ss.getId());
}
```

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [DeleteDimensionRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#deletedimensionrequest)

Comment: Thanks for all your help, you are amazing! One more question, can you make it transfer the rows and offset +2 columns so that when the archive is done, it timestamps the current date and time for each row in column A and stamps the sheet name that the rows came from in column B? "11/15/2021 | Sheet1 | Data..."

Comment: @usernametaken About your new question, I would like to support you. But unfortunately, I cannot understand your new question. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. In order to correctly understand your new question, can I ask you about the detail of it? By this, I would like to try to understand your new question. I could resolve your 1st question. But, I deeply apologize that I cannot resolve your new question soon. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: no problem at all! For the rows being transferred, I would like a timestamp added and the sheet name added. For example, if I archive a row from Sheet 1 to Sheet 2, I want the time and the original sheet name ("Sheet 1") added to every row that is moved.

Comment: @usernametaken Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot still imagine your new question. But I would like to try to understand your new question. So can you give me time to understand your new question? If you can give me time to do it, I'm glad. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: @usernametaken Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your new question, for example, when put `const date = new Date();` after the line of `var sheetId = firstSheet.getSheetId();`, and modify from `o.values.push(r);` to `o.values.push([date, "Sheet1", ...r]);`, is that the result you expect? If I misunderstood your new question, I apologize again.

Comment: @Taniake, that worked perfect, thank you!